# Generalization of twice the sum of previous integers equaling $n+n^2$

Tags: summation, integers

I've long noticed that you can find the next square number by adding the current and next integers together, as  a couple examples:

$$4^2+4+5 = 5^2 = 25$$

$$1000^2-1000-999 = 999^2$$

As far as I can tell, this generalizes to, for any integer n:

$$n^2+n = 2\sum_{i=0}^{n} i$$

(Edited based on Thomas' comment)

So, using the first example above: $$5^2+5 = 2*(1+2+3+4+5) = 30$$

This has always seemed kind of wonderful to me, and I was trying to find how this generalizes into the greater field of mathematics. Is this a theorem I just couldn't find, or is it related to some other similar conjecture/theorem? It's nigh impossible that I am the first to notice this, but I couldn't figure out how to Google this.

Comment: Previous integers?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. It’s related to $(x+1)^2=x^2+x+x+1$

Comment: What is $n_i?$ I think you just mean $\sum_{i=1}^n i.$

Comment: This formula (as interpreted by Thomas) is a rearrangement of the familiar formula $\sum_{i = 1}^n i = \frac{1}{2} n (n + 1)$. There are similar polynomial formulae for all $\sum_{i = 1}^n i^k$, where $k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples

Comment: The pattern is likely to break down for negative integers.  I'll let you explore that.

Comment: Legend has it that when the great mathematician Gauss was a child, his teacher gave his class the task of working out $1+2+3+\dotsb+100$, figuring it would keep the kids busy for a while. Gauss worked it out in seconds, using more-or-less the formula you have given. Anyway, you might do a search for "sum of an arithmetic progression", which generalizes what you have done. https://www.nctm.org/Publications/TCM-blog/Blog/The-Story-of-Gauss/

Comment: @GerryMyerson I find this legend plausible , but I guess Gauss needed $1-2$ minutes , I think a little time was needed to get the idea. And another little time for the calculation. Anyway , he presented the result in a very short time in comparison what the teacher expected it would take. Another question is whether Gauss was the FIRST to have discovered this method. I have a source claiming that.

Comment: Nice work! But not new: [Why the differences between each number of a $x^2$ sequence is always an odd number and increase by $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237530/why-the-differences-between-each-number-of-a-x2-sequence-is-always-an-odd-num)

Comment: Have you had a look at arithmetic progressions, kindlin?